# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using C APIs with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using the following code to find the server host name when connecting to a host using Bonjour (using functions from `<netinet/in.h>`
and `<arpa/inet.h>`) in my iOS Objective-C code. The code that I'm using (shown below) is from the Big Nerd Ranch iOS programming book, but was not originally written with ARC in mind.

```
- (NSString *)serverHostName
{
    NSArray *addresses = [desktopServer addresses];
    NSData *firstAddress = [addresses objectAtIndex:0];

    // the binary data in the NSData object is a sockaddr_in (which represents a network host)
    const struct sockaddr_in *addy = [firstAddress bytes];

    // convert 4-byte IP address in network byte order to a C string of the format xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    char *ipAddress = inet_ntoa(addy->sin_addr);

    // convert the 2-byte port number from network to host byte order
    UInt16 port = ntohs(addy->sin_port);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s:%u", ipAddress, port];
}
```

It occasionally crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line `char *ipAddress = inet_ntoa(addy->sin_addr);`, leading me to believe that `addy` is being disposed of too soon. I've tried looking into using `CFBridgingRetain()` or `CFRetain()` methods to prevent this but they either make no difference or seem to introduce more problems.

Any suggestions on what I should be looking for to quash this?

Comment: Are you sure NSData is not `nil` in those situations?

Comment: Yikes, I feel dumb. That seems to have been it.

Comment: Always check for `nil` :).  That's the first thing I do when something starts behaving like this.

Comment: The only way that could happen without an exception in the second line is if `addresses` had been nil as well. So while the check for nil is no bad thing, you might want to go back further to see if there's a problem in whatever `desktopServer` is doing to create `addresses`.